# C# WPF manipulate a bound string to replace everything before the last / and add then a different prefix

Tags: c#, wpf, string, datagrid

I am just learning Datagrids and had a question I could not find a clear answer to.
How would I be able to manipulate a bound string to replace everything before the last / and add then a different prefix.

This will be to show an image in a Datagrid.

For example what is bound to img variable is

img: "/img_banner/testBanner.jpg"

What finally needs to be output is this:

```
http://www.testsite.com/img_thumnail/testBanner.jpg
```

So far, I have found information about adding text to a bound string but I would like to remove part of the String.

Here is what I got so far:

```
<Image Source="{Binding img, StringFormat=http://www.testsite.com/img_thumnail{0}}" Height="40"/>
```

Is there any way to easily trim everything before the last / ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `IValueConverter`:

```
public class MyUrlConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if(value == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            var urlString = value as string;

            //now do whatever you want to do with the string
            //then return it
            return urlString;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

then add it to your resources

```
<Window.Resources>
   <local:MyUrlConverter x:Key="conv"></local:MyUrlConverter>
</Window.Resources>
```

and use it as:

```
 <Image Source="{Binding img,Converter={StaticResource ResourceKey=conv}}"></Image>
```

note that if the logic dependant on your view model then you better do your thing in the getter or the setter of your img property